# Как сохранить 2 файла в одном окне FileChooser?

Tags: java, javafx, файловая-система

У меня есть строка и лист строк, нужно их по отдельным файлам сохранить используя **fileChooser**. Может кто подскажет нормальную документацию по сохранению файла через **fileChooser**? Гугл ничего не дал адекватного. 
Дальше

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
           File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);
           try{
               FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
               BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
               bufferedWriter.write();
           }catch (IOException e){

           }
```

я не продвинулся

Comment: А что именно Вам нужно? Несколько строк сохранить по нескольким файлам? Тогда Вам нужно копать в сторону openDialog и режима выбора нескольких файлов.

Comment: Ну есть у меня строка А и лист строк В. В file1.txt надо записать строку А, в file2.txt записать лист строк В

Comment: Тогда, как я и написал, вам необходимо получить через new FileChooser().showOpenMultipleDialog() список выбранных пользователем файлов и в них записать что необходимо по вашей логике.

Comment: Но файлов не существует, нужно создать новые

Comment: Тогда JFleChooser Вам не поможет, только если выбрать папку сохранения. Сами файлы вы должны будете создать вручную и сохранить в выбранную папку.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте отталкиваться от того что Вам нужно:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class FileChooser {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String one = "одна строка";
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList("лист", "строк");

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            int answer = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (answer == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(file, "1.txt"))) {
                    fileWriter.write(one);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(file, "list.txt"))) {
                    for (String row : list) {
                        fileWriter.write(row + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Я правильно понял Вашу задачу?